# Query registered users details in Firebase

Tags: firebase

I am using simple email/password combination to authenticate users in Firebase. Is there a way to expose users' registration details like email or account creation date by the standard REST API or any other library (preferably React.js with ReactFire or Re-base)?

For example, I want to be able to get a list of all registered users or pass a UID to a query and retrieve email address or creation date. I know I can achieve this by storing the needed user details in my custom data store under the user UID for example, but I am looking to access the original data and not my own copy of it. I also understand that exposing such details might not be a recommended practice as it causes a security risk, but I still want to explore the possibility of achieving this.

Comment: Also see https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html#section-storing

Answer (score 1):

Firebase does not expose that data through any API. Like you've said, the only option is for you to store that data in your Firebase instance, and then query it there.