# Firebase - Auth - discover users who signed up but not verified email

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I've set-up a Firebase project which I am using for it's user authentication module. I am also using the [firebaseui-web](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web) project from Github.

My redirect on sign-on is working fine per this code:

```
// FirebaseUI config.
var uiConfig = {
  'signInSuccessUrl': 'MY_REDIRECT.html',
  'signInOptions': [
    firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
  ],
  // Terms of service url.
  'tosUrl': '<your-tos-url>',
};
```

When the page loads (i.e. MY_REDIRECT.html) I'm checking the status of the user to see if they have verified their e-mail, and if not then invoke the `sendEmailVerification` [method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#sendEmailVerification):

```
checkLoggedInUser = function() {
  auth.onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
      // is email verified
      if(user.emailVerified) {
        // show logged in user in UI
        $('#loggedinUserLink').html('Logged in:' + user.email + '<span class="caret"></span>');        
      } else {
        // user e-mail is not verified - send verification mail and redirect
        alert('Please check your inbox for a verification e-mail and follow the instructions');
        // handle firebase promise and don't redirect until complete i.e. .then
        user.sendEmailVerification().then(function() {
          window.location.replace('index.html');
        });
      }
    } else {
      // no user object - go back to index
      window.location.replace("index.html");
    }
  }, function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
};

window.onload = function() {
  checkLoggedInUser()
};
```

All good so far - Firebase is doing what I want! Thanks guys :)

However, in the Firebase Console UI there doesn't appear to be a way of seeing if a user actually went to their inbox and clicked on the link to perform the verification. The UI looks like this:

[image]

I've run basic tests and the User UID doesn't change before and after verification has taken place.

So, here's my question - did I go about the e-mail verification correctly? If so (and therefore the UI doesn't show me verified vs unverified) is there an accepted method of accessing these two sets of users in the Auth module? I can't see the way to access the underlying table of UIDs and their properties (including the `emailVerified` property). I don't mind having to write more code if the functionality isn't in the Console - just looking to get nudged in the correct direction for my next step.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is currently no way in the Firebase Console to see whether a specific user's email address has been verified. There **is** an [API to get a list of users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth#listUsers), but you can't filter on whether they're verified or not.

You can check whether the currently authenticated user's email address is verified with:

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.emailVerified
```

You cannot prevent who signs up. But you can easily ensure that only users with a verified email address can access (certain) data. For example:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null && auth.token.email_verified",
    "gmailUsers": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "auth.token.email_verified == true && 
                   auth.token.email.matches(/.*@gmail.com$/)"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The above rules ensure that only users with a verified email address can read any data and only users with a verified gmail address can write under `gmailUsers`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification. I am using this logic to prevent people signing up with e-mails like `mickey@mouse.com` as my preference is to be able to collect genuine contact information of the users wanting to use the site. Would your recommend a different approach on my part? I'd assume the ability to vet fake e-mail addresses would be a reasonable requirement. Understood that using social media logins would work around this. Thanks again.

Comment: So there is no way to access a full list of users of my project? That just seems a bit strange - is the workaround to build a secondary database as new people sign up? I feel I must be misunderstanding something. Feel free to ask me to start a new question if that's appropriate.

Comment: If anyone comes across this then go here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35613533/query-registered-users-details-in-firebase?rq=1